# bottom align divs at bottom of the window

Tags: css

I'm trying to align bunch of fixed positioned chat boxes at the bottom of the window. Tried `vertical-align: bottom` but did not work.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="message">Message 4</div>
    <div class="message">Message 3</div>
    <div class="message">
        Message 2 <br />
        <div>Message 2</div>
        Message 2
    </div>
</div>

#container{
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.message {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;    
    background: #ccc
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49RqX/41/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.message {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /*float: left remove this*/
}
```

Comment: I was looking at a fiddle, trying to figure out why it worked with the `display: inline-block` without the `vertical-align: bottom` http://jsfiddle.net/49RqX/42/

Comment: default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline` so I guess that's why it works

Answer (score 0):

Change your #container position to absolute.

Also, make sure your container is not inside another container or element with a specified position, or the positioning will be relative to that container, and not the browser window.